# How to render edges without faces?

Tags: rendering, freestyle

I wanted to improve my understanding in perspective. I created simple scene with rays from every cube's vertex and these rays meeting in one point. Now I want to render these rays. These are only edges without any faces and I can't render them.

What I tried:

1. When I mark them like freestyle edge, they don't render.
2. When I use skin modifier, only one of the edges became thicker.
3. Also I tried to move this edges into a collection for freestyle, it still doesn't render.

[image]

With skin modifier:
[image]

Render:

[image]

File:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) toggle xray

[image]

2.) in edit mode mark your vertices

[image]

3.) right mouse tap -> merge vertices -> at center

[image]

4.) tab -> object mode

5.) add skin modifier

result:

hint: you can change the thickness of the skin by selecting all vertices in edit mode -> ctrl-a -> s -> move cursor

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the 3D view window, view menu, there are the options "viewport render image" and "viewport render animation", which will render any kind of combination of lighting and overlays you choose (what you see is what you get), and it's very fast.

[image]